# PHP PDO Connecting To MSSQL Failing on Server Side

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm working on a php application that is hosted on a linux box (however currently testing on a mac), that remotely accesses MSSQL on a windows machine.

I have configured FreeTDS and the dblib extension. Confirmed these with phpinfo().

My code is as such:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("dblib:host=$host",$user,$pass);

    $db = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

I'm getting:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)
>   in the browser.

When I change anything about the host name, the error changes to showing an unknown host name.

I went on the server, into the event logs and found that every time I tried to connect, this was showing:

> "The login packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid;
>   the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the
>   client library. "

I've looked online, and haven't been able to find any info on this based on this context.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `$host` (just the basic format)? Have you tried specifying a db in the connection

Comment: I actually did specify it in the connection, just removed it for the sake of simplicity.

$db = new PDO("dblib:host=database1111.something.com:1111",$user,$pass);

I did notice if I had the incorrect port, the error changed. Also, I'm seeing failed login attempts on the box,  so it's definitely getting to the box itself.

Comment: I think the format should be `dblib:host=something.com:1111;dbname=database1111`

Comment: database1111 is the name of the server, not the db.  I'm actually not specifying the database name for this current test.  Just trying to connect to the box for now.  I attempted adding a dbname= and that didn't change the error on either side.

Comment: ah gotcha. One can see how that might be misconstrued :)